# Build CSV from Array of Strings in Swift in a single line of code

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of strings in swift and I thought I could do:

`array.join(",")` to return a comma separated list of the elements

The error I'm getting is: `Array<String> not convertible to 'String'`

How can I do this correctly in as little code as possible.

I can do it with a loop to build a string but I thought there was a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **Swift 2**,

```
array.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Answer (score 10):

Given an array of strings:

```
var x = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

the correct syntax to join strings is:

### Swift 1.2

```
",".join(x)
```

### Swift 2.0

```
x.joinWithSeparator(",")
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew i wasn't far off!

Comment: I'm getting "could not find member join", do I need to import something?

Comment: ah, my array was an array of Ints instead of Strings

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 4**

```
let array:[String] = ["one", "two","three"]

array.joined(separator: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3**,

```
values.joined(",")
```